# Can a humanoid creature, specifically a player character, be born on the Astral Plane?

Tags: dnd-5e, lore, planes, aging

I've been looking at the "This is Your Life" tables from *Xanathar's Guide to Everything*, and in particular there's an entry on the Birthplace table on page 62:

> 98      On the Astral Plane or the Ethereal Plane

However, the DMG says this about the Astral Plane on page 47:

> Creatures on the Astral Plane don't age or suffer from hunger or thirst. For this reason, humanoids that live on the Astral Plane (such as the githyanki) establish outposts on other planes, often the Material Plane, so their children can grow to maturity.

So it would seem that it would be impossible for an embryo to grow inside, say, a githyanki mother, so doesn't that make giving birth on the Astral Plane impossible?

Comment: I think the actual question is "will my health insurance cover that" ...

Answer (score 15, accepted):

### My water broke, time to go to the <s>hospital</s> astral plane!

You don't hunger, thirst, or age on the astral plane, but I really doubt that includes putting labor on pause.

Perhaps there's an organization or cult that thinks being born on the astral plane will grant magical powers, etc. and so they wait for the mothers to go into labor and then ship them off into their astral plane birthing facility.

(But also, it's listed as an option in XGTE, so RAW, it must be possible.)

Comment: I think I know where I want to move my base to.